# JUnit testing a java method,is it normal to test methods without a return type or should i use a different type of testing for them?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I am testing a program as part of a college assignment, i have tested some methods that return a Boolean to see if they are correct, im wondering is it standard practice to check void methods with JUnit? or is there another way.I will post one of the methods here as an example. 
Thanks

It is a quiz game program and this method accepts an int, which is defining the year the questions will be selected from.if statements then check the year passed in and sets the questions from a question class(that are defined as objects) not sure whether you need to know that or not to answer my question.

Thanks

```
  public GamePlay(int decade)
    {
        this();
        questions = null;
        if(decade== 1960)
        {
            questions = Questions.QuestionSetFrom60s();


        }
        else if(decade== 1970)
        {
            questions = Questions.QuestionSetFrom70s();

        }
        else if(decade== 1980)
        {
            questions = Questions.QuestionSetFrom80s();

        }
        else if(decade== 1990)
        {
            questions = Questions.QuestionSetFrom90s();

        }
        else if(decade== 2000)
        {
            questions = Questions.QuestionSetFrom2000s();

        }
        else if(decade== 2010)
        {
            questions = Questions.QuestionSetFrom2010s();

        }
        ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon(questions[questionIndex].mediaFilePath);
        lblMediaPlayer.setIcon(pic);

        questionIndex = 0;

        lblDisplayQuestion.setText(questions[questionIndex].textQuestion);
    }
```

I am adding this is to try explain where I am getting the questions from

```
public class Questions 
{

    public static boolean AccountCreation(String userName, String password)
    {

        return true;
    }
    /**
     * method to return array of questions from chosen decade
     * @return
     */
    public static QuestionObject[] QuestionSetFrom60s()
    {
        QuestionObject pictureQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        pictureQuestion.textQuestion = "Name This Character";
        pictureQuestion.dataType =  0;
        pictureQuestion.rightAnswer = "charlie brown";
        pictureQuestion.mediaFilePath = "Charlie Brown.jpg";

        QuestionObject themeTuneQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        themeTuneQuestion.textQuestion = "Name This Theme Tune";
        themeTuneQuestion.dataType =  1;
        themeTuneQuestion.rightAnswer = "the waltons";
        themeTuneQuestion.mediaFilePath = "the waltons.wav";

        QuestionObject videoQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        videoQuestion.textQuestion = "Who had a hit with the song ? Are You Lonesome Tonight";
        videoQuestion.dataType =  2;
        videoQuestion.rightAnswer = "elvis presley";
        videoQuestion.mediaFilePath = "";

        QuestionObject questionArray [] = {pictureQuestion,themeTuneQuestion,videoQuestion};

        return questionArray;
    }
    /**
     * method to return array of questions from chosen decade
     * @return
     */
    public static QuestionObject[] QuestionSetFrom70s()
    {
        QuestionObject pictureQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        pictureQuestion.textQuestion = "Name This Character";
        pictureQuestion.dataType =  0;
        pictureQuestion.rightAnswer = "worzal gummidge";
        pictureQuestion.mediaFilePath = "worzal gummidge.jpg";

        QuestionObject themeTuneQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        themeTuneQuestion.textQuestion = "Name This Theme Tune";
        themeTuneQuestion.dataType =  1;
        themeTuneQuestion.rightAnswer = "black beauty";
        themeTuneQuestion.mediaFilePath = "the adventure of black beauty.wav";

        QuestionObject textQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        textQuestion.textQuestion = "Which Group Performed The Song SOS";
        textQuestion.dataType =  2;
        textQuestion.rightAnswer = "abba";
        textQuestion.mediaFilePath = "";

        QuestionObject questionArray [] = {pictureQuestion,themeTuneQuestion,textQuestion};

        return questionArray;
    }
    /**
     * method to return array of questions from chosen decade
     * @return
     */
    public static QuestionObject[] QuestionSetFrom80s()
    {
        QuestionObject pictureQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        pictureQuestion.textQuestion = "Name This Character";
        pictureQuestion.dataType =  0;
        pictureQuestion.rightAnswer = "falcor";
        pictureQuestion.mediaFilePath = "Falcor.jpg";

        QuestionObject themeTuneQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        themeTuneQuestion.textQuestion = "Name This Theme Tune";
        themeTuneQuestion.dataType =  1;
        themeTuneQuestion.rightAnswer = "et";
        themeTuneQuestion.mediaFilePath = "ET.wav";

        QuestionObject videoQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        videoQuestion.textQuestion = "Who had the hit Beat It in 1982";
        videoQuestion.dataType =  2;
        videoQuestion.rightAnswer = "michael jackson";
        videoQuestion.mediaFilePath = "";

        QuestionObject questionArray [] = {pictureQuestion,themeTuneQuestion,videoQuestion};

        return questionArray;
    }
    /**
     * method to return array of questions from chosen decade
     * @return
     */
    public static QuestionObject[] QuestionSetFrom90s()
    {

        QuestionObject pictureQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        pictureQuestion.textQuestion = "Name This Character";
        pictureQuestion.dataType =  0;
        pictureQuestion.rightAnswer = "tommy pickles";
        pictureQuestion.mediaFilePath = "tommy pickles.jpg";

        QuestionObject themeTuneQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        themeTuneQuestion.textQuestion = "Name This Theme Tune";
        themeTuneQuestion.dataType =  1;
        themeTuneQuestion.rightAnswer = "the crystal maze";
        themeTuneQuestion.mediaFilePath = "the crystal maze.wav";

        QuestionObject videoQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        videoQuestion.textQuestion = "Which 90's Sitcom Featured 6 Friends That Sat Around In A Coffee Shop?";
        videoQuestion.dataType =  2;
        videoQuestion.rightAnswer = "friends";
        videoQuestion.mediaFilePath = "";


        QuestionObject questionArray [] = {pictureQuestion,themeTuneQuestion,videoQuestion};

        return questionArray;
    }
    /**
     * method to return array of questions from chosen decade
     * @return
     */
    public static QuestionObject[] QuestionSetFrom2000s()
    {


        QuestionObject pictureQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        pictureQuestion.textQuestion = "Name This Character";
        pictureQuestion.dataType =  0;
        pictureQuestion.rightAnswer = "walter white";
        pictureQuestion.mediaFilePath = "walt.jpg";

        QuestionObject themeTuneQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        themeTuneQuestion.textQuestion = "Name This Theme Tune";
        themeTuneQuestion.dataType =  1;
        themeTuneQuestion.rightAnswer = "two and a half men";
        themeTuneQuestion.mediaFilePath = "two.wav";

        QuestionObject videoQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        videoQuestion.textQuestion = "What is the main character of the sopranos";
        videoQuestion.dataType =  2;
        videoQuestion.rightAnswer = "tony";
        videoQuestion.mediaFilePath = "";

        QuestionObject questionArray [] = {pictureQuestion,themeTuneQuestion,videoQuestion};

        return questionArray;
    }
    /**
     * method to return array of questions from chosen decade
     * @return
     */
    public static QuestionObject[] QuestionSetFrom2010s()
    {


        QuestionObject pictureQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        pictureQuestion.textQuestion = "Name This Character";
        pictureQuestion.dataType =  0;
        pictureQuestion.rightAnswer = "elsa";
        pictureQuestion.mediaFilePath = "frozen.jpg";

        QuestionObject themeTuneQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        themeTuneQuestion.textQuestion = "Name This Theme Tune";
        themeTuneQuestion.dataType =  1;
        themeTuneQuestion.rightAnswer = "game of thrones";
        themeTuneQuestion.mediaFilePath = "Game.wav";

        QuestionObject textQuestion = new QuestionObject();
        textQuestion.textQuestion = "Who starred in the 2013 version of house of cards";
        textQuestion.dataType =  2;
        textQuestion.rightAnswer = "kevin spacey";
        textQuestion.mediaFilePath = "";

        QuestionObject questionArray [] = {pictureQuestion,themeTuneQuestion,textQuestion};

        return questionArray;
    }

}//end of class
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043819/junit-testing-void-methods.  But in your case that you posted, you actually don't have a void method.  You posted a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To test some code you first need to make it testable. Have you ever heard about test driven delevelopment (TDD)?

In the example you provided probably you can't modify the code. If you can then extract the logic of choosing the question set into a separate method and test it as a method with return value.

If you can't modify the code I think you should be able to query the "questions" field of the GamePlay class instance. I hope you have something like getQuestions method or the field itself is public/protected/default - thus accessible to the junit test case.

In the worst case if the field is private and do not have any public getters so you may use Java reflection to access the field. But I believe this could be quite "bad practise" exercise.

Once you get access to the field you could use the test approach proposed by Deh.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is correct since you mostly use the Assert class provided by JUnit to test your methods.

```
@Test
public void testQuestions() {
    Gameplay bean = new GamePlay(1960);
    Assert.assertNotNull(bean.getQuestions());
}
```

In the example above if questions is null then JUnit will consider the test failed and you can know that your constructor did not assigned the question set. On the contrary if it's not null JUnit will consider it as a success.
The assertNotNull method is just one example.
You can find more examples [here.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/asserts.html) 
 
**EDIT :**

I edited my example to fit the constructor provided by the OP.

Comment: The OP is specifically asking about methods that don't have a return value

Comment: im getting an error an the getQuestions() saying "The method getQuestions() is undefined for the type GamePlay" does this mean i need to include the class where the getQuestions method is in my test case?

Comment: @Mick O'Gorman getQuestions() is representing the getter for questions. As i read your constructor questions seems to be a class attribute.

Comment: I don't think I am using a get method as such as I am using question Objects, I have added my code in from the other class where I retrieve the question set from in my question if it helps?

Comment: I changed it to  assertNotNull(Questions.QuestionSetFrom60s()); and this seems to be working as when i change assertNotNull to assertNull I get an error so I am confirming here that I am not getting a null returned?

Comment: By doing a blind assertNotNull I could change your production code in a variety of ways to make it invalid but the test would still pass.  You need to consider what exactly the /behaviour/ you want to see is and write your tests according to that

Comment: @MrWiggles my example should be valid for testing that questions is set no? (Asking for confirmation)

Comment: If all you really care about is "is the questions field set" then yes, but that alone is a really poor test case, you want to know that the logic you've applied has worked correctly, i.e. you say `GamePlay(1960)` but any valid decade passed in will make this test pass

Comment: Sure but for me OP just wanted an example to understand the way JUnit work and I said it was just for testing that questions is set .