# How to test a void class method without arguments with Xcode Unit Test

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I have a class having a void method without arguments and would like to know if that kind of methods is testable with unit tests? If yes then what should be tested?

Context:

I have a viewcontroller and would like to present an actionsheet with a cancel button.

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController {
    func showLoginError() {
            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Erreur", message: "Nous ne sommes pas parvenu à vous connecter, vérifiez vos informations.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let closeAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) in
                self.userAddressField.becomeFirstResponder()
            })
            alertController.addAction(closeAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

Comment: Please add more context. What language / framework are you using ? Why do you thing there is something special testing with XCode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test anything that leads to **observable** behavior or that has **effects** on objects that you can control.

In other words: most likely, the intention of a void method is to change same *state* within an object/data store/... so in that sense, you can either:

- simply check the corresponding state before/after calling the method
- use some mocking framework to ensure that an expected call on a mock given to the code under test did take place

Ideally, you prefer tests of the first category. For more insights, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246038/unit-testing-void-methods) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043819/junit-testing-void-methods). Different languages, but giving the *theoretical* background that universally applies.