# Create Junit test for Void method

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I am learning unit testing, I have some confusion, I have one Void method, Can you please explain to me how can I create a unit test for this method.

```
public void eat(Food food){

mAmountOfEatenFood += food.eatFood(mNeededAmountOfFood - mAmountOfEatenFood);
if(mAmountOfEatenFood == mNeededAmountOfFood){
    System.out.println(mName + " has eaten " + mAmountOfEatenFood + " and will not be hungry for a while..");
    mAmountOfEatenFood = 0;
    mIsHungry = false;  
}else{
    System.out.println(mName + " has eaten " + mAmountOfEatenFood + " and is still hungry..");
    System.out.println("Needs= " + mNeededAmountOfFood);
    mIsHungry = true;
}
```

}

Comment: I think that this topic was covered by the following post:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043819/junit-testing-void-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043819/junit-testing-void-methods)

Comment: what do you want to test in void method ?

Comment: @Deadpool Actually I got a new project, in which I need to create a unit tests, I started working on it and complete some Util classes, but when I come to a Void method, there is some logic, on that time I don't know how can I create a test for that, What actually I need to test in this. hope you understand my point.

Comment: for void methods , you just use `Assert.assertEquals()`

Comment: @VishwaRatna then how can i cover 5-6 line logic inside that method?

Answer (score 1):

This method looks like it changes the state of object which calls it, lets say the object is called FoodConsumer.

The `eat(Food)` changes the state of two variables (`mAmountOfEatenFood` and `mIsHungry`).
So, to know if you need to feed that object again the getter method for `mIsHungry` is needed. It would be good to have getter for `mAmountOfEatenFood`.
The "obvious" result of `eat(Food)` is if the object is still hungry.

In test method, you need to have an instance of FoodConsumer. Therefore, later after calling `eat(Food)` you could call smth like `isMHungry()` and assert if it's true or false. Additionally you could call `getMAmountOfEatenFood()` to check if after eating insufficient amount of food it has proper value estimated by `food.eatFood(....)`.

For a little simplification, you could change the `eat(Food)` to boolean (even for test only) and return true/false just after setting the same value for `mIsHungry`.

Next, some magic, which we can't see now happens in:

```
food.eatFood(mNeededAmountOfFood - mAmountOfEatenFood)
```

If this isn't any kind of library method and you have access to it, then it would be good to have tests convering if value returned by `eatFood` is good.

I can't say exactly (because of magic in `eatFood`), but it looks like there is on case uncovered by this method, what if the FoodConsumer over eats (I'm thinking of some conversion rate inside the `eatFood` which could be over `1`).
For example, if `neededFood` is `100` and `eatenFood` is `90`, then the `10` goes to `eatFood` which multiplicates that amount by `5`. So the `eatenFood` is incremented with `50` resulting in `140` which is not equal with the `amountOfNeededFood`.
Simple fix would be to just change your `if` condition to:

```
if(mAmountOfEatenFood >= mNeededAmountOfFood){
```

In the end, lets compare this case witch something like `repository.save(User)`.
Something similar to `repo.save(User)` is a void method having only a side effects.
Those side effects aren't being explicitly shown when calling `save`, but then the `repo` must/should contain of methods which could return some values telling if the inner state of `repo` was changed.
When testing the repository, to check if `save` method works correctly, the assertions in test are checking if repository returns the same number of users which were saved and, for example, if the first/second/third user object contains the same values of the objects used when `save`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, its helpful